# Parameter is returning null when send through ajax call for validating if PAN Number already exist or not Using validation-engine

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-ajax, jquery-validation-engine

I'm working on an asp.net MVC application. As per our requirements we need to check whether inserted data already exists or not at runtime. And for implementing that facility I've used validation-engine plug-in. And used ajaxCall in it. But when ajax call is triggered it's not fetching value of that particular field and parameter is being null in JSONResult method of my controller.

Here is my Change in **validationEngine-en.js**

```
"ajaxPANCheckCall": {
                "url": '/Registration/Check_ifPanExistsForEntity',
                "extraDataDynamic": ['#ED_txtPan'],
                "alertText": "* This pan is already taken",
                "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait",
                "alertTextOk": "* This PAN is available"
            },
```

Here is my **view.cshtml**

```
 @Html.TextBox("ED_txtPan", null, new { @class = "form-control uppercase validate[required,funcCall[PanTest],ajax[ajaxPANCheckCall]]", maxlength = 10 })
```

Here is my **JSONResult Method in RegistrationController.cs** file

```
public JsonResult Check_ifPanExistsForEntity(string number)
    {
        cMGR_ENT_ENTITY_DETAILS objED = new cMGR_ENT_ENTITY_DETAILS();
        objED.PAN = number;
        bool exists = objED.ifPanExists_Entity();
        if (!exists)
        {
            return Json(Utility.SuccessResponse(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(Utility.ErrorResponse("Pancard No already exists."), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

When I leave txtPan field it first popups *Validating, please wait* but then when I checked my developer tools it shows status pending for ajax call. And in JSONResult method my `string number` is being null and because of that it shows error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of object.

My question is that why my ajax call is not sending my parameter and what is actual way to send field data to that specific method using validationEngine-en.js

If any help is possible it would be appreciated.